# outlook mail times out

Tags: email, connection

When I try to go to outlook.live.com in firefox or chrome it always times out.  If I use thunderbird or if I use my phone with only a wifi connection they get my messages immediately.  If I try to use an incognito / hidden window the outlook sign-in screen appears but after pressing sign in it returns ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Clearing cache or disconnecting and reconnecting the router does not help. No problems with other sites.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you clear the cookies (for Outlook) in both Firefox and Chrome?
If yes, try opening Outlook in Firefox's Safe/Troubleshoot Mode:
[Hold your "Shift key" before opening Firefox]

You can also check for Cookie restrictions. At times, you need to add an exception for the specific site using the "Manage Exceptions" button.

For Chrome also, you can take a look at the cookie settings & possibly add an exception for Outlook.

Do let us know how that works out for you.

Cheers,

Comment: Before trying these solutions I connected the laptop to my phone's hotspot and both FF and chrome worked straight away.  Then I checked FF and it had a skype site mentioned in additional permissions. Removed this and now FF works OK.  I cleared the cookies for chrome but it is still timing out when I press sign in. How do I add an exception in Chrome?

Comment: For chrome: 
- Click the three horizontal lines at the top-right corner (next to the Address bar)
- Click on Settings >> Show Advanced Settings >> Change Proxy settings >> Security Tab
- Click on "Trusted Sites" icon >> Sites
- Enter the website URL >> Click Add >> Close >> OK

This should work.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Mate 20.04 and chrome Version 100.0.4896.75 (Official Build) (64-bit). I had to use a different route. Settings>>Advanced>>System>>Open your computer's proxy settings>> This message appears: "When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration. But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man google-chrome-stable for more information on flags and environment variables.".